# How can we show that the jump measure of a càdlàg process is a *counting* measure?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, levy-processes

Let $E$ be a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space, $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ be an $E$-valued càdlàg process on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ and $$\pi_\omega(B):=\sum_{\substack{s\:\ge\:0\\\Delta X_s(\omega)\:\ne\:0}}1_B\left(s,\Delta X_s(\omega)\right)\;\;\;\text{for }B\in\mathcal B([0,\infty)\times E)$$ for $\omega\in\Omega$.

Using that a regular function on a bounded interval has countably many jumps, we know that $\{s\ge0:\Delta X_s(\omega)\ne0\}$ is countable and hence $\pi_\omega(B)\in\mathbb N_0\cup\{\infty\}$.

> But how do we see that $\pi_\omega$ is a counting measure$^1$?

I don't think that this is necessary, but I've only seen this claim under the assumption that $X$ is a Lévy process. However, this shouldn't be important.

This is stated as an exercise in [exercise 16 of this lecture notes](https://www.ceremade.dauphine.fr/%7Epoisat/files/jump-processes.pdf#page=11). So, I guess it's simple, but I've no idea how we should approach this.

---

$^1$ Remember that a measure $\mu$ on a measurable space $(S,\mathcal S)$ is called *counting measure* if

1. $\mu$ is *purely atomic*, i.e. $$D_\mu:=\{x\in S:x\text{ is an atom of }\mu\}$$ is countable and $\mu\left(D_\mu^c\right)=0$;
2. If $x\in D_\mu$, then $$\mu(\{x\})=1.$$

Moreover, $x\in S$ is an *atom* of $\mu$ iff $\mu(\{x\})\ne0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technical remark: $\pi_{\omega}$ will be a counting measure in the set which $\lbrace s \geq 0: \triangle X_s  \neq 0 \rbrace $ is countable (it has probability one). We will fix $\omega$ is in that set .

First claim :
Consider $\lbrace  t_n \rbrace $ the countable set which $\triangle X_{t_n}  \neq 0 $.  Define $D:= \lbrace (t_n,\triangle X_{t_n} ), n \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace $. \
Then $\pi_{\omega}(D^c)$ is clearly zero because each pair $(s,\triangle X_s)$ such that $\triangle X_s \neq 0$ belongs to $D$ (therefore each element in the sum is zero).

Second claim: Suppose $\pi_{\omega}(t_n,\triangle X_{t_n}) >1$ . Then there is at least one $m \in \mathbb{N}, \ m \neq n$ such that:
$$ (t_n, \triangle X_{t_n})= (t_m, \triangle X_{t_m}) $$ because $\mathbf{1}_{ \lbrace (t_{n},\triangle X_{t_n}) \rbrace } (s, \triangle X_s) \neq 0$ for at least two $(s, \triangle X_s)$ such that $(\triangle X_s) \neq 0$.
This is absurd because $t_n \neq t_m$ if $n \neq m$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll check it out now. But regarding your technical remark: I guess you're saying this, because you think the paths of $X$ are only almost surely càdlàg? In order to rule out this unnecessary problem, I've assumed that all paths are càdlàg. Or did I miss something else?

Comment: No, you are right!

Comment: Suppose  $\pi_{\omega}(D^c) \neq 0$. Then there is at least one $s $ such that $\triangle X_s \neq 0$ and $(s, \triangle X_s)  \in D^c$. On the other hand if $s$ is a non-continuity point then there is a $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $t_n =s$. However the points $(t_,n, \triangle X_{t_n})$ belongs to $D$.  (  This answer is to clarify a deleted question)

Comment: Yes, sorry. Figured it out. It's trivial. The sum is $0$ (it is a sum over an empty index set), since for all $s\ge0$ it holds $(s,\Delta X_s(\omega))\in D^c$ iff $\Delta X_s(\omega)=0$.

Comment: No, that wouldn't be correct, but it should be "$x\in S$ is an *atom* of $\mu$ iff $\mu(\{x\})\ne0$". Thanks for mentioning.

Comment: Indeed, now I commited a typo.

Comment: What's the purpose of your second claim? If the goal is to show that for every $s\in I_\omega:=\lbrace s \geq 0: \triangle X_s(\omega)  \neq 0 \rbrace$, the point $(s,\Delta X_s(\omega))$ is an atom with $\pi_\omega$-measure $1$, then this should be rather trivial follow from the definition of $\pi_ω\left(\left\{\left(s,\Delta X_s(\omega)\right)\right\}\right)$. What's worrying me more: From this latter conclusion we see that every point in $D=\{(s,\Delta X_s(ω)):s\in I_\omega\}$ is an atom of $\pi_\omega$ with measure $1$. But how do we see that these are actually *all* atoms of $\pi_\omega$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134598/discussion-between-foe-and-0xbadf00d).